# Entropy in calculation of work from heat engine

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I was studying Exergy of a fixed mass from the book "Thermodynamics An engineering approach – Eight edition" by Yunus A Cengel and Michael A Boles. And in this section of the Exergy chapter they apparently use

$$\mathrm dS=-\frac{\delta Q}T$$

Whereas entropy is given by $$\mathrm dS=\frac{\delta Q}T$$ Or am I doing something wrong?

Image of the page attached here.[image]

**Edit**: Thank you for your replies. I am aware that $\mathrm dS=\frac{\delta Q}T$

But above the Eqn 8-14 in the image, they have replaced $\frac{T_0}T \delta Q$ by $-T_0dS$. So apparently they have taken $\mathrm dS=-\frac{\delta Q}T$. This is where my confusion is.

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: It might just be me being thick, but I don't understand what question you are asking. You might want to reformulate to clarify the specific question you are asking unless other people get the point

Comment: Hi I answered your question about heat and entropy; however, I unless I misunderstood it seems you don't have a question about exergy and so I would suggest removing exergy from your question for the clarity of future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the expressions:

$$\text{d}S=\frac{\delta Q}{T}$$

where $\text{d}S$ is the infinitesimal change in entropy of the system $S$, $T$ is the temperature of the system and $\delta Q$ is the heat flow into the system. $\delta Q$ is the heat flow into the system as we are using the convention that the first law is written as:

$$\text{d}U=\delta Q+\text{work and particle number terms}$$

which gives:

$$\text{d}U=T\text{d}S+\text{work and particle number terms}$$

Entropy awlays increases for the universe and is only conserved for reversible processes. As entropy is not conserved in general then $\text{d}S$ isn't necessarily a flow of entropy to the system by is just the change of the entropy of the system as the entropy of the system can increase without a relative decrease in the entropy of the surroundings.

In the text they are using the convention:

$$\text{d}U=-\delta Q+\ldots$$

And so the sign on $\delta Q$ changes giving $\mathrm dS=-\frac{\delta Q}T$; but, confusingly in the text above the more conventional form $\mathrm dS=\frac{\delta Q}T$ is stated. However, at the part you underlined, they substitute in the correct form for the given convention being $\mathrm dS=-\frac{\delta Q}T$.

Comment: Thanks Chris Long. The information is helpful, I learned something new. But my actual question was that in the image I have attached, above the eqn 8-14, they have apparently used $\mathrm dS=-\frac{\delta Q}T$, or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: Ah, yes as far as I can tell it should be $\mathrm dS=-\frac{\delta Q}T$ as the are using the convention $\text{d}U=-\delta Q+\ldots$ and this is what they substituted in where you have underlined. Its normally written as $\mathrm dS=\frac{\delta Q}T$ as the convention I used in my answer seems to be more common (at least in most of the reading I have done).

Comment: Okay, this makes sense now. The convention they have chosen is different. Thanks again Chris. Maybe you can add this to your answer and then I can accept that.

Comment: Glad I could help! Added to my answer.